# Cosine transform of a Sine function

Tags: fourier-analysis

We all know that cos and sin are two orthogonal functions hence their dot product is zero over a domain. Then in the cosine transform how can a sine function be represented by a cosine basis  function?

PS : this question may be silly, but please be gentle enough to provide an explanation

Comment: Basically, your problem lies in the lack of precision when you say “over a domain”. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're orthogonal over $[-\pi,\pi]$, but not over $[0,\pi]$ – which is the domain one uses for the cosine transform. In fact, taking the cosine transform of $\sin x$ is equivalent to taking the Fourier series of $\lvert\sin x\rvert$, which is the $\pi$-periodic extension of the sine function from $[0,\pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: i wasn't aware of the [0,π] domain of the cosine transform. your answer made it clear, thank you